# insert new row after each 10 items in apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a `List<String>` that has few elements and I want to write these elements into an Excel sheet using Apache POI. Also I want to put the data into separate rows after each 10 items.  For example, my list has following elements :

```
["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff","ggg","hhh","iii","jjj","kkk","lll","mmm","nnn","ooo","ppp","qqq","rrr","sss","ttt",....]
```

I want this in excel sheet in following format

```
        col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10
row1 :  aaa,  bbb,  ccc,  ddd,  eee,  fff,  ggg,  hhh,  iii,  jjj
row2 :  kkk,  lll,  mmm,  nnn,  ooo,  ppp,  qqq,  rrr,  sss,  ttt
```

Can this be achieved through Apache POI?

I have tried the following (I am really bad in loops)

```
public void csvUpdateWorksheet1(String fileName, String sheetName, List<String> data) {

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);

    logger.info(data.size());
    int rownum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellValue(data.get(i));    
    }        
    csvWriteToFile(workbook, fileName);            
}
```

Comment: Yes, it can be achieved. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Please see the Apache POI Quick Guide to learn how work with it: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

Comment: @aeinstein83 please **update your question** and add the code with your attempt to use the library. Please **do not post your code in a comment**, also **do not post a wall of code**.

Comment: i have added the code that i am trying

Comment: @aeinstein83 I cleaned up the formatting, spelling and grammar in your post. Please endeavor to follow good style guidelines in these areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create the next row once you have created 10 cells in the current row.

```
int r = 0;
int c = 0;
int maxCellsPerRow = 10;
Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
for (String str : data)
{
    Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
    cell.setCellValue(str);

    c++;
    // Create and advance to next row if needed.
    if (c >= maxCellsPerRow)
    {
       c = 0;
       r++;
       row = sheet.createRow(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int rownum = 0;
int colnum = 0;
int itemsPerRow = 20;
String outfilename = "test.xls";
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
// add some values ...

HSSFWorkbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();

HSSFSheet sheet = book.createSheet(

HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rownuw);

for(String s : values) {

   HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(colnum);
   cell.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(id));
   colnum = (column+1)%itemsPerRow;
   if(colnum == 0) {
       rownum++;
       row = sheet.getRow(rownuw);
   }   
}

File f = new File("src/main/resources/films.xls");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

book.write(fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Comment: The method `createCell` should be used, `createColumn` doesn't exist in `Row`.  And a `Cell` is created, not a `Col`, which doesn't exist.  The OP is asking for 10 cells per row, not 20.  The `Row` should be created with `createRow`, not `getRow`.  Typo: s/rownuw/rownum

Comment: where are we setting cell values here?

Comment: it is missing ... but the code is creating the cell ... so setting the cell value ain't that difficult. the code is only pseudo code anyway, ommitting, for example, the creation of the workbook etc.

Comment: @aeinstein83 - This answer is attempting to show you how to create a new row after every 20 items.  The actual code to set the cell's value is irrelevant.  You should focus on trying to understand what is happening rather than looking for code to copy/paste.